# JavaScript - Select all elements with [data-some] attribute not having a specific value

Tags: javascript, custom-data-attribute

My Project uses plain JavaScript. I want to select elements which are not having a data-some attribute's value as 'abcd'. 
I tried the following.

```
 :not([data-some="abcd"])
```

this selector returns only elements not having [data-some]. But I want to select only elements not having data-some's attribute as 'abcd'. It can have [data-some="gtf"].

Any help is highly appreciated.

NOTE: I have pasted only the selectors as I need only them. Most stackoverflow questions have answer for selecting elements without a specific data attribute.

Comment: So you want a subset of those elements that have a *data-some* attribute, but not value "abcd"? Does it have to be a selector, or can it be a combination of say selector and *Array.prototype.filter*? Then you want `[data-some]:not([data-some="abcd"])`.

Comment: I just want selectors.. and not using Array.prototype.filter.

Comment: @RobG Please make your comments as an answer. The [data-some]:not([data-some="abcd"]) is what I expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a single, though fairly complex, selector:

```
[data-some]:not([data-some="abcd"])
```

Be careful with compatibility, you may need a simpler selector plus some script depending on the hosts you need to support.

E.g.

```css
[data-some]:not([data-some="abcd"]) {
   background-color: #ffff66;
}
```

```html
<p data-some="abcd">data-some="abcd"</p>
<p data-some="zzz">data-some="zzz"</p>
<p data-some="">data-some=""</p>
<p>no data-some attribute</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 var test = document.querySelectorAll(':not([data-some="abcd"])');
               for (var i in test) if (test.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                    (test[i].style.background = "#DCDCDC");
                }
```

```css
p, h1{
background: #ff7f7f;
}
```

```html
<div >
<h1 data-some="abcd">hello</h1>
<p data-some="abcd">hello</p>
<p data-some="gtf">hello</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the *if* test in the *for..in* loop does nothing useful. The enumerable own properties of *test* (which is a NodeList) are the indexes for the elements (0, 1, 2, etc.), so it's just a complex way of doing a *forEach* loop over the elements. It doesn't exclude the elements that don't have a *data-some* property, so delivers the same result as the style rule `:not([data-some="abcd"]) {background-color:#dcdcdc}` which the OP doesn't want.

Answer (score 0):

Get all elements that have the attribute `data-some` except those with the value `"abcd"`

```
$("div[data-some]").not("div[data-some!='abcd']");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xz5et4tr/

Comment: Your not selector needs outer quotes as well.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is possible, **if** you can use `Array.prototype.filter`:

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-some]");
const result = Array.from(elements).filter(el => el.dataset.some !== "abcd");
console.log(result);
```

```html
<div data-some="abcd"></div>
<div data-some="gtf"></div>
<div data-some="ooo"></div>
```

It grabs every element with `data-some` attribute, creates an array of elements, and filter out these that don't meet condition `el.dataset.some !== "abcd"`.